# String to dict/json like format

Tags: python, json, node.js, python-3.x, flask

I'm finding it difficult to turn a json like string into a json/dict object, I've got the data like this

```
{"key1":"value1","key2":[{"key2.1":"value2.1"},{"key2.2":"value2.2"}]}
```

When running `type` on the variable it tells me it is of class str i.e `<class 'str'>`. I need to get the string into a json or dict like format so I can extract all of the values named value...

I've tried `json.loads`, `json.load`, `json.dumps`, `ast.literal_eval` but nothing seems to be working. I've tried adding `['` and `']` either side of the string but still no luck. Any ideas? Thanks

EDIT:

I'm using a nodeJS backend sending a request to a flask server, the nodeJS axios request is this

```
get_values: (key_one, key_two) =>
  axios.post('http://localhost:5000/example', {
    key_one: key_one,
    key_two: key_two
  }).then(res => res.data),
```

on the flask side I'm doing this

```
@app.route('/example', methods=["POST","OPTIONS"])
def example():
  convert_data = request.get_data()
  string_data = convert_data.decode('utf8').replace("'", '"')
  new_string = "'''" + string_data + "'''"
  print(json.loads(new_string))
```

Then I get the an error

Comment: "Nothing seems to be working" - How is it failing? What do you get? `json.loads` and `ast.literal_eval` should both work just fine on your example input. Are you sure they're failing? Example: `json.loads('{"key1":"value1","key2":[{"key2.1":"value2.1"},{"key2.2":"value2.2"}]}')` produces the expected `dict`.

Comment: the `{"key1":"value1","key2":[{"key2.1":"value2.1"},{"key2.2":"value2.2"}]}` you provided is already a `dict`, why do you still need to serialize it?

Comment: @ShadowRanger running that gives a long output the last line of which is `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

Comment: @MaThMaX running `print(my_string.get('key1'))` gives the output `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'`

Comment: I ran `json.loads(s)` with `s = '''{"key1":"value1","key2":[{"key2.1":"value2.1"},{"key2.2":"value2.2"}]}'''`. No problem.

Comment: As @mshsayem says, it works for your example, but I suspect your example isn't remotely related to what you're actually doing. Post a [MCVE]; as is, it's impossible to answer your question (because `json.loads` *works* for what you've provided).

Comment: @ShadowRanger Hopefully it should be complete now

Comment: What error you get ?

Comment: @kip same as the errors in my first comment, starts with `[2018-03-27 03:55:33,110] ERROR in app: Exception on /example [OPTIONS]` ends with `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)` it's a fairly large error

Comment: The only other piece of information from the error that seems to be of use is `raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None` which is the penultimate line from the error if that helps

Comment: @W22 I think that you need to use `request.form['key']` to get the `POST` values, if the `POST` send the data like `JSON`  in the body request then you can try with `request.get_json()`

Comment: Why are you replacing single quotes?

Comment: @kip `request.form['key']` gives me errors, `request.get_json()` works however I'm struggling to get further information from it, I'm running into the error `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`, which I've tried before to solve before by adding headers to the request, i'll try again unless there's a different way of getting the information?

Comment: @mshsayem Following previous answers on stackoverflow about getting a string into json format

Answer (score 1):

I modified your function a bit:

```
@app.route('/example', methods=["POST","OPTIONS"])
def example():
  convert_data = request.get_data()
  string_data = convert_data.decode('utf8')
  print(json.loads(string_data))
```

It seems `string_data` is already a perfectly formatted json string that you can pass into `loads`. I removed the replacement of `'` with `"` which seems unnecessary, and definitely the addition of `'''`, which will make this string become Python multiline string literal syntax but definitely break json compatibility, which is what your error tells you too:

> json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

This should be a lot closer to what you wanted. Otherwise let me know what exactly is inside `string_data` when you run this.

Comment: It runs into an error on the final line, first line of error `Error on request:` followed by a fairly large error about random library calls then ends with `raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

Comment: When running `type(string_data)` I get `<class 'str'>` and the output is`{"key1":"value1","key2":[{"key2.1":"value2.1"},{...`.

Comment: Looking good actually. Maybe it's the encoding... Have you tried  `string_data = request.get_data(as_text=True)`?

Comment: The request itself works, trying to use `string_data['key1']` gets the error `TypeError: string indices must be integers`. Trying `string_data.get('key1')` has the error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'`. Trying `json.loads(string_data)` gets the error `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`. I've found a solution using regex' and other things to solve the issue but still not good I guess, using `request.form.get('key1')` doesn't crash but it prints `None`.

Comment: Ofc `string_data` is a string so none of the getitem (dict-like) access works, but if the content is indeed a valid json string, there should be no trouble parsing it with `json.loads`. Must be something wrong with it. Can you show me a full `print(string_data.__repr__())`?

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if I understand the question correctly. But, let's say you have a string as follows:

var a = {
        "key1": "value1",
        "key2": [{
            "key2.1": "value2.1"
        }, {
            "key2.2": "value2.2"
        }]
    }

Then you can do something like this:

```
try {
  const dictionary = JSON.parse(a)

  console.log(dictionary.key1) // This will print value1

  Object.keys(dictionary).map((key) => {
    console.log(dictionary[key]);
  });

} catch(e){
    // do something with error here
}
```

Comment: It is not python.